# How to validate if firebase admin is already autenticated in Code JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I validate if Firebase admin has been already authenticated when running Node JS within Visual Studio Code

I'm trying to get data from collection as show below, but snapshot always comes up null, even the collection and filter exist and are valid.
I'm looking into the console and nothing is being logged there

```
try {

  db.collection("coll_name").where("id", "==", 'filter_value').get().then(snap => {
  ...
  });

  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error description ....');
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share your complete code as is including where you initialize Firebase Admin? These small snippets do not help

Comment: Firstly, if the admin SDK is not properly initialized, you will not get any query results it all.  It will just give you an error.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "always comes up null".  Secondly, your try/catch here is not going to catch any problems with the query.  You need to chain a `catch` method after the `then` in order to get any errors. try/catch only works if you use `await` to get the results from the returned promise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.